# D7 how to check does the uploaded photo have EXIF data?

Tags: 7, media

I'm using Drupal 7 with module [EXIF](https://www.drupal.org/project/exif).
I want to check if uploaded photo have EXIF data if not then don't allow the user to add this content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check a file that is being added through a file field on a content type you can use [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x). Unless you need the exif module for other reasons you can do without this module and just use the [exif_read_data](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) function. Make sure to enable to the [exif](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php) extension in php.

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'article') {
    // Still needs some checking here to see if a file is provided
    $fid = $node->field_file['und'][0]['fid'];
    $file = file_load($fid);
    $hasExif = exif_read_data($file->uri, 0, true);
  }
}
```